# How to Declare a global variable for storing the no.of .decimal values for a number(Variable)?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I need a global variable for storing the no.of Decimal values for a number (variable).... Below is the scenario...

I have a store Procedure where I declare all the decimal numbers at the start as shown below

```
Declare @timeID as Decimal(15,**3**),
Declare @BusinessID as Decimal(15,**3**)
```

I need a variable which stores the decimal count say

```
Declare @decimalcount as Integer, @decimalcount=3
```

which I can use it in all the declartion i have done like

```
Declare @timeID as Decimal(15,@decimalcount)

Declare @BusinessID as Decimal(15,@decimalcount)
```

so by changing the value at one place would change all the values in the code....
Is this possible  ?

Comment: I think you need dynamic SQL to do this.

Comment: Are you referring to the `scale` of your numbers? (i.e. allowed decimal places)

Comment: Yes dana.. the decimal places..

Answer (score 0):

Look into user-defined data types, as implemented via the `CREATE TYPE` command. I haven't used them and so can't give detailed advice, but in general it lets you set up a "new" datatype based on existing ones, and then in subsequent code you can use that new datatype. Lessee...

```
CREATE TYPE phkTest from decimal(15,3)
GO


DECLARE @Foo phkTest

SET @Foo = 1
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.1
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.12
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.123
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.1234
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.12345
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.6789
PRINT @Foo

SET @Foo = 1.1235
PRINT @Foo
GO

DROP TYPE phkTest
```

Yep, pretty much works as advertised. You don't get a variable with the precision, but you do get consistency. (And I bet the precision could be fished out of the system tables, with some effort.)

Comment: thanks it looks ok..but when i use the concept inside a stored procedure its throwing error...

Comment: I believe you have to treat the user-defined data type like a table: create it, then use/reference it within the stored procedure.

Comment: I dont know how to acheive this.. I tried the following code  but couldnt get the idea of how to do this inside the procedure.                                    CREATE TYPE phkTest AS TABLE
 (
  @convfactor Decimal (15,3)
 )

Comment: This is a complex topic. Check out the SQL 2008 BOL for technical details [ https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb522526(v=sql.105).aspx ], and here's a brief article from SQL Server Central discussing their use [ http://www.sqlservercentral.com/blogs/steve_jones/2012/09/19/creating-a-user-defined-table-type/ ].